# Should I think of Next.js as a backend stack?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I wonder if Next.js should be considered as a frontend technology stack or a backend.

If you use Next.js, it looks like a monolithic architecture when you consider the possible parts from developing a simple SPA to writing an API.

Comment: Generally, Next.js can be only a frontend when statically generated (SSG) or full-stack when server-side rendering (SSR) - never just a backend.  There are frameworks like keystone.js built on Next that allow you to use it as frontend, backend, or full-stack.

Comment: @Sean W
In summary, it is not correct to classify Next.js only as a backend stack, and should I understand how much area it can cover depending on whether it uses SSR or middleware?